# Why isn't my bootstrap classes working?

Tags: html, netbeans, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't find what I did wrong. The syntax looks okay but Netbeans shows an error every time I call a class from bootstrap. Is something wrong with my settings? Help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style=" background-image : url('2.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img src="logo_final.png" alt="logo" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-left: 45%;"><br/> <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the error netbeans complains about?

Comment: @Capricorn it says "Class not found" error even though it exists in the link.

Comment: For me, the error is that I had accidentally imported "only grid CSS", also try to change the bootstrap version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css this link on your browser find `col-12` class. It is not present there so it's not working.

You can replace `col-12` with `col-lg-12` and `align-items-center` with `text-center` as below snippet. It's working in below snippet.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Login</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style=" background-image : url('2.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=48" alt="logo" style="width:100px; height:100px;"><br/> <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Since Bootstrap is responsive, you have to tell it what size (or larger) you are targeting. You are right that just `col-12` isn't there, but something like `col-md-12` would be where we are targeting screens of medium size or larger. Also, in Bootstrap 4 `col-12` is valid and targets all screen sizes but the question is using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: You can find `col-*` classes from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp). You can always manually add them to your project and use it.

Comment: Thank you for this, but no classes work. It gives "Class not found" error. The same code runs on my friend's computer but it doesn't in mine. Is there perhaps something wrong with the settings or something? I can't find what :(

Answer (score -1):

**Try changing this**

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**To this**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I saw a few other questions like this. Try this : Try running the same code in another text editor. So that we can corner the problem to Netbeans.